# Why does ggplot2 allow grouping by invalid aesthetic mappings?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble understanding how grouping works in ggplot. Suppose I have a dataframe with date, value, categorical, and a dichotomous variable like so:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(date = sample(seq(as.Date('2015/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 20),
                   values = rnorm(20, 0, 1),
                   categories = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 20, replace = TRUE))
data$pre_post <- ifelse(data$date <= '2018/01/01', "pre", "post")
```

If I group by the 'pre_post' variable (dichotomous) using aes(group =), I get:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = values, color = categories, group = pre_post)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Using aes(by =), the results change to:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = values, color = categories, by = pre_post)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

In my current use case, 'by=' gives me the desired results but I don't know how to explain what exactly it is doing and why. Especially since, as @markus points out that 'by=' isn't even a valid aesthetic and that replacing it with 'foo=' would do the same thing:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = values, color = categories, foo = pre_post)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: `by` is not a valid aesthetic and has nothing to do with the base R function, change it to `foo` and you'll see. What 'goes wrong' in the first place is that you specify a `group` aesthetic. Technically this is fine but - as you see - doesn't give desired output. The `color` aesthetic seems enough here as it takes care of the grouping. ...

Comment: Interesting. That helps. I've updated the post to reflect what I may have left out in  trying to understand the issue (or perhaps non-issue). In this toy example, data$pre_post splits up the continuous lines into a time before and a time after while still grouping and coloring the distinct lines (as opposed to one connected line) according to data$categories.

Comment: I'm baffled as to why setting anything, whether its 'foo' or 'by', to a variable seems to actually use that variable in a sensible (to me) way..

Comment: I think you were looking for `ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = values, color = categories, group = interaction(categories, pre_post))) + 
    geom_line()`. No idea why `foo = pre_post` is doing anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the examples and explanations in [*Aesthetics: grouping* of the `ggplot2` documention](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html) correctly, *the group aesthetic maps a different line for each subject*.

`group = pre_post` seems to take precedence over the grouping by the `color` aesthetic enforcing to draw a single line connecting all "pre" data points and another line connecting all "post" data points.

In order to get *six* different lines for each combination of `categories` and `pre_post` you may follow [Axeman's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460008/why-does-ggplot2-allow-grouping-by-invalid-aesthetic-mappings#comment106960273_60460008) to use `interaction()`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = values, color = categories, group = interaction(categories, pre_post))) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

or you may use a different aesthetic like `linetype`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = values, color = categories, linetype = pre_post)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Using an undefined aesthetic like `by` or `foo` causes the data to be grouped as well but without effect on the aesthetical appearance.

---

However, grouping a line chart may lead to *a loss of information* as can be seen here:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = values, color = categories)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Without grouping by `pre_post` the blue line extends into 2018 which was not visible on the previous plots.

To avoid the loss of information I prefer to plot the data points as well as the lines in order to mark the end points of the line segments or to show a single data point:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = values, color = categories, linetype = pre_post, shape = pre_post)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(aes(label = date), data = data[data$categories == "c" & data$pre_post == "post", ],
             hjust = -0.1, vjust = -0.1, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

`geom_label()` is optional and only used in this post to highlight the single data point.